# Discard rows and corresponding colums of a matrix that are all 0

Tags: python, numpy

I have a square matrix that looks something like

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

eg the output of this would be:

```
0 0 0 | 0 0 |
1 0 0 | 1 0 |
1 1 1 | 0 0 |
- - - + - - +
1 1 1 | 1 1 |
1 1 1 | 1 1 |
- - - + - - +

0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

Notice how the 4th row and column are all 0, as well as the last. I would like to delete rows and columns if and only if the ith row and the ith column are all 0s. (Also note that the first row of 0s remains since the first column contains non-zero elements.)

Is there a clean and easy way to do this without looping through each one?

Comment: Is this a list? Or a np.array? Or...?

Answer (score 4):

Assume `a` is a numpy array with same sizes on both dimensions:

```
# find out the index to keep
keep_idx = a.any(0) | a.any(1)

# subset the array
a[keep_idx][:, keep_idx]
#array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
#       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a 7*7 data frame, similar to your matrix, then the following code does the work:

```
row_sum = df.sum(axis=1)
col_sum = df.sum(axis=0)

lst=[]

for i in range(len(df)):
    if ((row_sum[i] == 0) & (col_sum[i]==0)):
        lst.append(i)

df1 = df.drop(lst, axis = 1).drop(lst, axis = 0)
```